# In 16.04, why do updates show up in 3 separate locations?

Tags: updates, 16.04

For me, software updates show up in 3 separate places:

- Under the 'About This Computer' overview,
- Via the 'Software Updater' and
- In 'Ubuntu Software'

I also get an OSD message telling me updates are available. This seems a bit much - which one should I use?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that, too.  I actually used terminal.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I stopped getting messages after that.